# Azure file systems after autoscale

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

If I have an App Service that listens for service bus messages and stores a file on the file system as a result of that message, will that file exist on another instance if we horizontally scale the App Service?

Answer (score 1):

All instances of a Web App in an App Service have a shared file system. This is how tools like blog engines are able to scale to multiple instances, while still sharing a common local-filesystem database (this is how Ghost works, for example). Any newly-added instances will have access to that shared storage.

Note: this is specific to scale-out and scale-in. When you change the *size* of instances, then there is different behavior (since data space grows and shrinks).

Comment: So, if it auto scales out, then 10 minutes later, one instance handles a service bus message that creates a new file, that new file will be present on both instances?

Comment: If you are writing to the common (shared) file area, then yes.